# object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python

I have seen other posts on here but no one help me yet.
I'm very confused. Please comment if you know what's going on here.

My code:`

```
from scipy.integrate import quad 
from sympy.mpmath import *

k=0.0
i=0.0

def i_2(x, k):
        return cos(2*pi*k/sqrt(1-(1-k**2)*cos(x)**2))-1

while k<=0.2:

        k = k + i
        result = quad(i_2, 0, pi, k, args=())
        print(result)
        i=0.1`
```

Comment: Please add the the exception you get with the complete traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The wild import you use here :

```
from sympy.mpmath import *
```

Shadows the `quad` you imported here:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
```

See:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sympy.mpmath import *
print(quad.__module__)  # sympy.mpmath.calculus.quadrature
```

Instead, flip the import order:

```
from sympy.mpmath import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
print(quad.__module__)  # scipy.integrate.quadpack
```

Or (much) better yet (and preferred) avoid using a wild import altogether:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sympy.mpmath import cos, pi, sqrt
print(quad.__module__)  # scipy.integrate.quadpack
```

Also, you'll need to remove `args=()` for your code to work:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sympy.mpmath import cos, pi, sqrt

k=0.0
i=0.0

def i_2(x, k):
    return cos(2*pi*k/sqrt(1-(1-k**2)*cos(x)**2))-1

while k<=0.2:
    k = k + i
    result = quad(i_2, 0, pi, k)
    print(result)
    i=0.1
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 0.0)
(-1.8582851152906286, 8.932955791447448e-09)
(-3.376947682538414, 1.3760007564395206e-08)
(-4.297856700579023, 2.455769416130881e-12)
```